# paste merge .txt files to one by next column

Tags: bash

I have multiple text files. One text file it's one column in database. I would like merge all files to one like

address.txt

```
Warsaw
Gdansk
Poznan
```

cars.txt

```
Honda
Audi
```

etc files

FINAL OUTPUT

```
Warsaw  \t Honda
Gdansk  \t Audi
Poznan
```

I try using `paste` like `paste *.txt | column -s $'\t' -t` but result was not complete.

Note: this file is Windows like files:
`file` result:

```
UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Maybe this is problem?

Comment: `paste` already uses tabs to delimit the columns, what's the point of piping through `column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
paste <(dos2unix <address.txt) <(dos2unix <cars.txt)
```

or

```
paste <(sed 's/\r$//' address.txt) <(sed 's/\r$//' cars.txt)
```

Output (columns separated by a tab):

```
Warsaw  Honda
Gdansk  Audi
Poznan
```

Comment: In, my case result it's not completly.

Comment: Ok, it's works thanks, but when I get 10 files like this, can I do it in for loop eg?

Comment: I would like to do this because I have in my dir 20 files to merge. Can you tell me how I should do this in loop?

Comment: This should work with GNU sed: `sed -i 's/\r$//' *.txt; paste *.txt`

Comment: `sed -i 's/\t$//' *.txt; paste *.txt | column -s $'\t' -t` its completly works for me but in first line I have one space, how to remove them?

Comment: Yes. Try to replace `-t` by `-tn`.

Comment: `column: illegal option -- 'n'`